# jQuery: really simple self-made infinite scroll

Tags: ajax, jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I know there are multiple plugins out there however I wonder how I can make my own thing work the way I want.

First off, when scrolling to the bottom of my page I want to trigger a function called `ajaxLoadActivity` which is now triggered with a "Show More" button.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

            if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) )

                if ( $('ol.astream > .loadCount:last > li').attr('id') == "noMoreActivities" )
                    return false;

                ajaxLoadActivity('bottom', true);
                console.log('fired');

        });
```

I have the problem that probably everybody encounters when trying to do this himself. The problem is that the function is fired multiple times. The function `ajaxLoadActivity` does all the ajax stuff and appends `<li>` items to an existing `<ol>`. The function works perfect when just using it with the "Show More" Button.

However I wonder how I can trigger the same function when simply scrolling to the bottom of the page. But I want to call it only once - then wait till the stuff is loaded - and only then allow the function to be fired again if the bottom is reached again.

And I have an exception that is already in my sample code above … if my last element has an id of `noMoreActivities` I don't want the function to be fired again, because then there are no more activities.

Any ideas how I can fire the function only once and wait till the request happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `$.post` you can return it in your `ajaxLoadActivity` function then check to see if it's running

```
var ajax;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) )

        if ( $('ol.astream > .loadCount:last > li').attr('id') == "noMoreActivities" )
            return false;

        if (ajax) {

            return false; // don't make another request, let the current one complete, or
            // ajax.abort(); // stop the current request, let it run again
        }

        ajax = ajaxLoadActivity('bottom', true);
        console.log('fired');

});

function ajaxLoadActivity(one, two) {

    return $.post(/* stuff */);
}
```

Comment: But this is fired only once, right? So if I scroll to the bottom the function is called, however I want the function to fire again once I've reached the bottom again

Comment: The `$(document).height()` will change so it should get fired again

Comment: Would someone mined explaining why you use this particular condition: $(document).height() - $(window).height() )  when the scrolltop - at the bottom of the page -  does not always appear to be larger than document.height -window.height?  Why not just use scrolltop ===document.height?

Answer (score 0):

$(window).scrollTop() **==** ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) will make it execute the call only once. Try it.